# simple_html_dom.php failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wamp, simple-html-dom

Im trying to use the simple html dom parser within WAMP - for some reason I can't get the php file to recognise the parser - I'm using example code from the parser website and it is not working - the code is as follows;

```
 <?php
include_once('C:\wamp\www\reports\simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_digg() {
// create HTML DOM
$html = file_get_html('http://digg.com/');

// get news block
foreach($html->find('div.news-summary') as $article) {
    // get title
    $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
    // get details
    $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p', 0)->plaintext);
    // get intro
    $item['diggs'] = trim($article->find('li a strong', 0)->plaintext);

    $ret[] = $item;
}

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);

return $ret;
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!

// "http://digg.com" will check user_agent header...
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');

$ret = scraping_digg();

foreach($ret as $v) {
echo $v['title'].'<br>';
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>'.$v['details'].'</li>';
echo '<li>Diggs: '.$v['diggs'].'</li>';
echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

So far I have tried having the path as follows;

```
 include_once('C:\wamp\www\reports\simple_html_dom.php');
 include_once('http://localhost/reports/simple_html_dom.php');

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
```

Here are the error messages I recieve

> ) Warning: include_once(../../simple_html_dom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\reports\example_scraping_digg.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../../simple_html_dom.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\reports\example_scraping_digg.php on line 2

I also get another error on line 6..;

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in C:\wamp\www\reports\example_scraping_digg.php on line 6

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer - It is greatly appreciated.

The file in question is located here : C:\wamp\www\reports\simple_html_dom.php
which is why I'm so confused - Thanks again for your help

Comment: read the error message carefully and check the file is exist or not on that path and check permission of file.

Comment: Can you please share your directory structure?

Comment: Thanks for your responses - the file directory is correct - which is why I'm so baffled, it is located as follows..  C:\wamp\www\reports\simple_html_dom.php       I have tried using just the file name as it is in the root folder - but that doesn't seem to work for me either

Comment: Where is *this* file, the one that you show here?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking at the problem - It was incorrect php.ini settings in the WAMP folder - Thanks